# Bootstrap 4 Carousel not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Building a page with a carousel slider.

Bootsrap 4 Carousel is not working:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="/wp-content/themes/tarps/assets/img/aaatarps-banner.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="/wp-content/themes/tarps/assets/img/aaatarps-banner.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000})
</script>
```

When I open the Chrome developer tools, the Chrome console shows an error as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Not quite sure what I have missed?

Comment: That error generally means jQuery was not loaded.  Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Yep you were right, very silly of me :) fixed. Problem with link to js.

Comment: Are you including jquery ? `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem was link to js resource.